# Content-disposition tags http headers not present in Response

Tags: iis-7, content-disposition, akamai

we have a website on IIS 7 , with Akamai CDN

A feature to download images is implemented in our website. This feature is implemented using a customhandler to look for **forcedownload=true** appended with image URL's.

Intermittently , the download feature doesnt work. On our analysis , we found that the content-disposition header tag is removed from the httpresponse. The feature works fine or our developer , integration , QA servers with same configuration

Akamai says , the origin server is removing the content-disposition tag. Can you tell is if if you have faced this issue before.

Questions:

- Can firewall/load balancer settings remove the content-dispostion tag ?
- IIS server Configuration
- Is this because of any configuration at Akamai.
- Is this scenario plausible - Server receives multiple requests for a image resource to download. Intial requests , have content-dispostion tag added , In subsequent requests the tag is removed. ?

Please suggest some debugging steps to resolve this problem or has anyone faced this issue with akamai

Answer (score 1):

Until you are able to replicate the issue by capturing headers, it hard to tel where the issue lies. But if Origin is causing the issue then why don't you to take advantage of Akamai? I mean based on file extensions you can set headers from Akamai configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with help from akamai support.

Since the  tags were getting stripped from akamai end. They made sure to add the tags from their edge server/.

The configuration was done by akamai on their servers and is now live .